# TweenSequence Ignores TweenSequence Items

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

Hi I want to continuously Fade an Image in and out in my Flutter App.
For That I use a TweenSequence:

```
AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> opacityAnimation;
  double opacity = 0.5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
    opacityAnimation = TweenSequence(
      [
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
            tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.5, end: 1.0).chain(
              CurveTween(curve: Curves.bounceIn),
            ),
            weight: 50),
         TweenSequenceItem<double>(
             tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.5).chain(
               CurveTween(curve: Curves.bounceIn),
             ),
             weight: 50),
      ],
    ).animate(animationController);
    animationController.addListener(
      () {
        setState(() {
          opacity = animationController.value;
          print(opacity);
        });
      },
    );
    animationController.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset("assets/images/buildup_0.png"),
          Opacity(
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/Logo_K.png"),
            opacity: opacity,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the animation just ignores the Tweens i gave it and animates between 0 and 1, jumps back to 0 and repeats. I can see that in my console due to due to the print statement. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution: Instead of setting opacity to animationController.value I needed to set it to opacityAnimation.value